# C# Array of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've consumed a web service with two classes "address" and "request."  One of the properties of the request object is an array of address objects:

```
request _req = new request();
_req.addresses = // expecting address[]
```

I know I'm doing this wrong (as I keep getting exception errors) so I'm hoping someone can help me out. How do I create an array of address objects and set the "_req.addresses" value equal to that object (address[])?  I get an "object reference not set to an instance..."  error on the second line, when trying to set the city value equal to the string _q.LocationA.City...  so these aren't working:

```
    address[] _address = new address[1];
    _address[0].city = _q.LocationA.City;
    _address[0].state = _q.LocationA.State;
    _address[0].street = _q.LocationA.Address;
    _address[0].zipCode = _q.LocationA.Zip;

    request _req = new request();
    _req.addresses = _address;
```

And I've tried this:

```
    address _address = new address();
    _address.city = _q.LocationA.City;
    _address.state = _q.LocationA.State;
    _address.street = _q.LocationA.Address;
    _address.zipCode = _q.LocationA.Zip;

    request _req = new request();
    _req.addresses[0] = _address;
```

Comment: For a `new request()`, is adresses == null ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: What exact exception are you getting, and at which exact line of code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your classes need to be instantiated separately from your array. C# won't call your constructor automatically, so that's why you get a NullPointerException in the first set of code. The second code fails because you're giving it a single object, instead of an array.

You essentially need to combine the two:

```
address[] _address = new address[1];
_address[0] = new address();
_address[0].city = _q.LocationA.City;
_address[0].state = _q.LocationA.State;
_address[0].street = _q.LocationA.Address;
_address[0].zipCode = _q.LocationA.Zip;

request _req = new request();
_req.addresses = _address;
```

Comment: Yeah, that did it.  I've never seen that (or tried doing this before) so I never would have tried that... thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code block you are not creating a new `address` object in the first element of the array; thus the null reference exception when you attempt to set the city member.  The fix for this is:

```
address[] _a = new address[1];
_a[0] = new address();
_a[0].city = ...
```

In the second code block you are not creating an array in the `_req.addresses` member.  The fix for that is:

```
...
_req.addresses = new address[1];
_req.addresses[0] = _address;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
address[] _address = new address[1];
    _address[0].city = _q.LocationA.City;
    _address[0].state = _q.LocationA.State;
    _address[0].street = _q.LocationA.Address;
    _address[0].zipCode = _q.LocationA.Zip;
```

To:

```
address[] _address = new address[1];
_address[0] = new address();
_address[0].city = _q.LocationA.City;
_address[0].state = _q.LocationA.State;
_address[0].street = _q.LocationA.Address;
_address[0].zipCode = _q.LocationA.Zip;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a generic list:

```
List<address> _addresses = new List<address>();
_addresses.Add(_address);

request _req = new request();    
_req.addresses = _addresses;
```

Comment: I tried this originally, but the _req.addresses property was giving an error because it was looking for "address[]" not List<address>... unless I missed something.

Comment: Check your Request class definition, how is the field addresses defined?

Comment: It's defined as "address[]" which is why I think "List<address>" isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Address
    {
        public string Street;
        public string City;
        public string State;
        public string ZipCode;
    }

```
public class Request
{
   public Address[] address;
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Address[] address = new Address[]{ new Address {
                    Street = "140 sw 8 st",
                    City = "Miami",
                    State = "Florida",
                    ZipCode = "33122"}};

        Request req = new Request();

        req.address = address;

    }
}
```

}